# Stepped configuration in Google Data Studio API issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio, gdscript

I'm currently building a Google Data Studio connector where I need to make use of the stepped configuration to achieve dynamic user input.

For example, connecting to Google Analytics will have a configuration of account -> properties -> view.

I want to achieve something exactly of this sort but when a user input the first answer from a dropdown, the connector should make an API request to pull data into the dropdown of the next config.

Please, how do I go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the parameters the user selects from "request.configParams" (in the getConfig function). Using your chosen parameter, you can do an API call to get the data you need so that you can set up your options for the stepped configuration.

Comment: Currently, I'm able to make 2 consecutive stepped configuration call (using the example in the documentation). But I'm having issues making the stepped configuration to return a third question. How can I go about this?

Comment: What I have done to get it working is create a variable within the getConfig function to conditionally assign either undefined or the value of the second step field. (var secondStepInfo = isFirstRequest ? undefined : configParams.yourSecondStepFieldNameHere). Then, create an if statement checking if that variable is not undefined, just need to put your third step logic within that conditional statement. (if (secondStepInfo !== undefined { //Insert logic for third step }))